# How to Compare two multidimensional associative arrays with differen items count

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional associative arrays with differen items count.
Important is that I don't know which aray will have more elements (A or B)

First array (A):

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catID] => 65
            [discount] => 10
            [productID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10887
                    [1] => 8508
                    [2] => 8350
                )

            [startDate] => 05/12/2022 12:00 am
            [endDate] => 10/12/2022 12:00 am
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [catID] => 66
            [discount] => 10
            [productID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13184
                    [1] => 10707
                    [2] => 8350
                )

            [startDate] => 10/12/2022 12:00 am
            [endDate] => 15/12/2022 12:00 am
        )
```

Second array (B):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [catID] => 72
        [discount] => 15
        [productID] => Array
            (
                [0] => 16239
                [1] => 16236
                [2] => 10887
                [3] => 13184
                [4] => 8524
                [5] => 13314
            )
        [startDate] => 12/12/2022 12:00 am
        [endDate] => 15/12/2022 12:00 am
    )
```

After compare  these arrays (A, B) I'd like to retrive something like that:

Array A(remove productID if exists in array B):

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catID] => 65
            [discount] => 10
            [productID] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 8508
                    [2] => 8350
                )
            [startDate] => 05/12/2022 12:00 am
            [endDate] => 10/12/2022 12:00 am
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [catID] => 66
            [discount] => 10
            [productID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10707
                )
            [startDate] => 10/12/2022 12:00 am
            [endDate] => 15/12/2022 12:00 am
        )
```

Array B(no changes):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [catID] => 72
        [discount] => 15
        [productID] => Array
            (
                [0] => 16239
                [1] => 16236
                [2] => 10887
                [3] => 13184
                [4] => 8524
                [5] => 13314
            )
        [startDate] => 12/12/2022 12:00 am
        [endDate] => 15/12/2022 12:00 am
    )
```

Comment: Should `1 => 8350` be removed from the second row in the first array because that product id is found in the first row of the first array?  That rule is not well defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Populate a flat "blacklist" array from your second array.

Loop over the first array's rows and filter the productId values against the blacklist array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DVK25))

```
$blacklist = array_merge(...array_column($b, 'productID'));

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_replace($row, ['productID' => array_values(array_diff($row['productID'], $blacklist))]),
        $a
    )
);
```

---

Or if you don't mind a classic `foreach()`, then this may be easier to read: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NLZ7H))

```
$blacklist = array_merge(...array_column($b, 'productID'));

foreach ($a as &$row) {
    $row['productID'] = array_values(array_diff($row['productID'], $blacklist));
}
var_export($a);
```